# Hiveserver Beeline Logging 2.0.1

Tags: hadoop, logging, hive, apache-hive, beeline

I didnt get any log while connecting the Hiveserver with beeline and getting exception as

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configurati
on: logging only errors to the console.
```

Because of that i cant able to Get my logs in Beeline.

could any one help me resolve this or guide me enable the logs in HIVE 2.0.1.

Comment: Could you please navigate to your `$HIVE_HOME/conf` folder and make a copy of `beeline-log4j2.properties.template` and rename as `beeline-log4j2.properties` , then restart the hive service and try?

Comment: i do tried these change !! still am getting error like this.